# python, redis: store on redis a multi-dimensional list. Best data type?

Tags: python, list, redis

i need to periodically store a python list like

```
[
[1, ...],
[2, ...],
[3, ...],
[4, ...]
]
```

1. i need to make it expire after some seconds and add new one (so i would like to create the list and fill it at once using my python list).
2. i need to retrieve sub_list of specific range for example: `[[2, ...], [3, ...]]`

using [this library](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) i was considering to use `lpush` to create and fill the list at once, `expire` to set the expire time after i created and filled it, `lrange` to get the specific range of my python sub_list

Am i using a good solution or there is something that better fit my needs?

Comment: Sounds like you should store each inner list (`[1, ...]` etc.) as a value (probably encoded as json or similar).  The keys should be the position in the outer list, maybe prefixed with a name for the whole thing.  This way accessing sublists is easy.

Comment: @Alfe  so i should i use (zadd)[http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.zadd]? because i don't think that using redis list is possible

Comment: Redis supports lists as well, but I have used it for strings only.  To my hammer that json-solution looks like a nail.  But feel free to store lists natively.  Why do you think it isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis only support one-level data structures, but you can break the rule using Json. So you could make each inner list a json string, and store this using redis list.

Answer (score 2):

Just use pickle

```
# store_objects_in_redis.py
'''
 Pickle (dumps) & set to store
 Get & and unpickle (loads) to retrieve
 #
 Courtesy: Armin Ronacher, http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/73/ 
'''

import redis
from pickle import loads, dumps

# Create client with default connection
client = redis.client.StrictRedis()
# An example complex object
stored_object = [{1,2,3}, {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, ['foo', 'bar']]

# store
client.set('obj', dumps(stored_object))

# retrieve
retrieved_object = loads(client.get('obj'))

# compare
print(stored_object==retrieved_object, '\n', stored_object, '\n', retrieved_object)

'''
Prints (Running in windows7)
== RESTART: K:/.../REDIS/store_objects_in_redis.py ==
True 
 [{1, 2, 3}, {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, ['foo', 'bar']] 
 [{1, 2, 3}, {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, ['foo', 'bar']]

'''
```

Comment: cant say enough that this answer doesnt get the recognition it deserves, instead of storing an entire list in the redis memory, better idea is to have redis store the latest entries and run a cron that pickles every 5 mins or so